# Scrapy Selector does not convert text to Selector object

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Stacking Selenium and Scrapy to scrape dynamic pages, I'm running into an issue where I can successfully capture all text of a dynamic page, but cannot convert to a Selector object. The method below works for other iBooks pages, but not the one used in the example.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://itunes.apple.com/ch/genre/bucher-belletristik-und-literatur/id9031?mt=11&letter=M')

page_text = driver.page_source # is valid HTML string

page_select = Selector(text=page_text)
>>>page_select
<Selector xpath=None data=u'<html><body><html xmlns:a0="http://www.w'>
```

What's going on here? It seems that Selector is re-fetching the page but all I want it to do is convert the text to a selector object.
I have scrapy configured to show me whenever a request is made and sure enough this comes through when setting page_select = Selector(text=page_text):

```
<class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'>
<200 about:blank>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I have scrapy configured to show me whenever a request is made"? Scrapy Selectors ([parsel](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/04e6e145ce6ad964435225fc953be15f6e1b6d1a/parsel/selector.py#L110) under the hood) don't do any network activity.

Comment: What part of the question does "What's going on here?" refer to? `page_select` looks fine

Comment: @paultrmbrth the data within `page_select` is only that short html string which contains none of the content that `page_text` contains. And I understand what you're saying about Selectors not doing network activity but when I do `page_select = Selector(text=page_text)` my scrapy logger kicks out `<class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'>
<200 about:blank>` if you run the code you'll see. It's weird.

Comment: That `'<html><body><html xmlns:a0="http://www.w'` is only how `Selector` instances are represented: only 40 characters of the HTML are printed ([see `__str__` and `__repr__`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/04e6e145ce6ad964435225fc953be15f6e1b6d1a/parsel/selector.py#L263)) but the document is complete. Sorry, I have no idea why the logger spits out `<class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'> <200 about:blank>`

Comment: sorry rookie mistake. The logger throws that out but i can still access all the data. `about:blank` threw me for a loop